# Wordpress plugin : Yop Poll with pie chart

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts, wordpress

Have you ever tried to integrate a pie chart with Yop Poll plugin ([visible here](http://wordpress.org/plugins/yop-poll/)) ?
I would like to render the polls results with a doughnut chart from [Highchart.js](http://www.highcharts.com).
But Yop Poll "only" integrates bar charts by default.

What are your recommendations to achieve this ?

Comment: I think you need to ask authors of Yop Poll plugin, how to achieve that.

Comment: Hi, I just post this [thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/yop-poll-visualize-results-with-a-donut-chart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put this javascript in my javascript template and it works, but that's not very pretty.

```
var poll_total = [];
    $( ".yop-poll-answers ul li:not(:last-child)" ).each(function( index ) {
        var lab_value = $( this ).find("label").text();
        var span_value = parseInt($( this ).find("span").text().replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ));
        var poll_couple = [];
        poll_couple.length = 0;
        poll_couple.push( lab_value );
        poll_couple.push( span_value );
        poll_total.push(poll_couple);
    });

        var series_update = [];
    $('.yop_poll_vote_button').click(function() {
        var chart_update = $('#container').highcharts();
      $( ".yop-poll-answers ul li" ).each(function( index ) {
        var span_value_update = parseInt($( this ).find("span").text().replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ));
                chart.series[0].data[index].update({
                    y: span_value_update
                });
    });
    });


    var colors = [ '#c5071b', '#a77eb1', '#a91a31','#8c6994', '#b05b85' ];
     Highcharts.setOptions({
            colors: colors,
             chart: {
                style: {
                    fontFamily: 'Arial'
                }
            }
     });
        Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function(color) {
            return {
                radialGradient: { cx: 0.5, cy: 0.3, r: 0.7 },
                stops: [
                    [0, color],
                    [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.1).get('rgb')]
                ]
            };
        });
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        legend: {
            layout : 'vertical',
            borderColor : '',
            itemMarginBottom: 30,
            itemStyle: {
               cursor: 'pointer',
               color: '#666666',
               fontSize: '12px',
               width:'200px',
            }
        },
        tooltip:{
            enabled:false
        },
        title:{
            text:''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                innerSize: '50%',
                dataLabels: {
                    connectorWidth: 0,
                    connectorPadding: 0,
                    distance: 10,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight:'bold'
                    },
                    formatter: function () {
                        return '<span style="color:'+colors[this.point.x]+';">'+ Math.round(this.percentage) +'%</span>';
                    },             
                },
                showInLegend: true
             }
        },
       credits: {
        enabled: false
       },
        series: [{
            data: poll_total
        }]
    });



function stripBorder_%POLL-ID%(object) {
    object.each(function() {
        if( parseInt(jQuery(this).width() ) > 0) {
            jQuery(this).width( 
                parseInt( 
                    jQuery(this).width() ) - 
                    parseInt(jQuery(this).css("border-left-width")) - 
                    parseInt(jQuery(this).css("border-right-width")) 
            );
            }
        else {
        jQuery(this).css("border-left-width", "0px");
        jQuery(this).css("border-right-width", "0px");
        }
    });
}
function stripPadding_%POLL-ID%(object) {
    object.each(function() { 
        jQuery(this).width( 
        parseInt( jQuery(this).width() ) - 
        parseInt(jQuery(this).css("padding-left")) - 
        parseInt(jQuery(this).css("padding-left")) 
        );
    });
}

function strip_results_%POLL-ID%() {
    stripPadding_%POLL-ID%( jQuery("#yop-poll-container-%POLL-ID% .yop_poll_li_result-%POLL-ID%") );   
    stripBorder_%POLL-ID%(  jQuery("#yop-poll-container-%POLL-ID% .yop-poll-result-bar-%POLL-ID%") );
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
    if(typeof window.strip_results_%POLL-ID% == "function")  
        strip_results_%POLL-ID%();
    if(typeof window.tabulate_answers_%POLL-ID% == "function") 
        tabulate_answers_%POLL-ID%();
    if(typeof window.tabulate_results_%POLL-ID% == "function")  
        tabulate_results_%POLL-ID%();
});

function equalWidth_%POLL-ID%(obj, cols, findWidest ) {
    findWidest  = typeof findWidest  !== "undefined" ? findWidest  : false;
    if ( findWidest ) {
        obj.each(function() {
            var thisWidth = jQuery(this).width();
            width = parseInt(thisWidth / cols); 
            jQuery(this).width(width);    
            jQuery(this).css("float", "left");    
        });
    }
    else {
        var widest = 0;
        obj.each(function() {
            var thisWidth = jQuery(this).width();
            if(thisWidth > widest) {
                widest = thisWidth; 
            }    
        });
        width = parseInt( widest / cols); 
        obj.width(width);    
        obj.css("float", "left");    
    }    
}

function tabulate_answers_%POLL-ID%() {
    equalWidth_%POLL-ID%( jQuery("#yop-poll-container-%POLL-ID% .yop-poll-li-answer-%POLL-ID%"), %ANSWERS-TABULATED-COLS% );
    //equalWidth_%POLL-ID%( jQuery("#yop-poll-container-%POLL-ID% .yop-poll-li-answer-%POLL-ID% .yop-poll-results-bar-%POLL-ID% div "), %ANSWERS-TABULATED-COLS%, true );
}

function tabulate_results_%POLL-ID%() {
    equalWidth_%POLL-ID%( jQuery("#yop-poll-container-%POLL-ID% .yop-poll-li-result-%POLL-ID%"), %RESULTS-TABULATED-COLS% );
    //equalWidth_%POLL-ID%( jQuery("#yop-poll-container-%POLL-ID% .yop-poll-li-result-%POLL-ID% .yop-poll-results-bar-%POLL-ID% div "), %RESULTS-TABULATED-COLS%, true );
    }

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    runOnPollStateChange_%POLL-ID%();
});

function runOnPollStateChange_%POLL-ID%() {

};
```